# SQL Error when trying to dynamically read from table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

The following code is causing some trouble. I'm trying to create a function that will create a token and check a specific table for one that matches. I'm getting this error message when the query runs.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB 
server version for the right syntax to use near ''comps' WHERE 'compUUID' = 'gDnn58MU5vAP1GxhP0LgOGToJQUrXmQhtZqbQvwDpqmqGbIY9B4F' at line 1
```

Here's the code

```
function genToken(table, col, length) {
let finalGen;
generator()
function generator() {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        if (i + 1 === length) {
            db.query("SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = ?", [col, table, col, result], (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        generator()
                    } else {
                        finalGen = result
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
}
return finalGen
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass in identifiers (column and table names) as SQL parameters.  You have to munge the query string to put them in.

Comment: I linked this question to an old question that I answered with an example of how to use the mysqljs library to pass identifiers. They use a trick - it isn't a query parameter in the traditional sense, they just copy the identifer name into the query, but they do it safely.

Answer (score 0):

"You cannot pass in identifiers (column and table names) as SQL parameters. You have to munge the query string to put them in"

Thanks Gordon Linoff